# toggle() accordion script not working

Tags: javascript, css, toggle, hide

I've run into a roadblock with this and can't seem to wrap my head around as to why this script will not run on my test page. I have jquery linked, followed by this script. this is my only script so i know its not a js conflict. fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dXWAY/7

```
var content = $('.content').hide();

$('.toggleBtn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.content').slideToggle();
    return false;
});

.toggleBtn {
    background:deepskyblue;
    display:block;
    float:Left;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.content {
    background:skyblue; 
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
}

 <a class="toggleBtn">Click Me!</a>

<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore accusamus porro modi ut itaque ipsum natus explicabo vero sequi beatae libero voluptatibus sit culpa debitis tempore! Sint eum ipsum consequatur!</div>
```

Comment: It won't work live, it only works on jsfiddle

Comment: Then upload your live code somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Your problem (on the live example) is that you're running the JS script you've written (in the *HEAD* section) before the DOM is loaded.

A simple fix would be to make that script run only after the document is ready. You can achieve this by simply entering it to the [document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var content = $('.content').hide();

    $('.toggleBtn').on('click', function() {
        $(this).next('.content').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: That plus the addition of switching the script to the bottom made it work. thanks.

Comment: @Blake You don't have to put the script in the bottom when you're using `document.ready()` :)